# Why `overflow-x` changes the height of the inline-block box in Firefox and IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, firefox

Take a look at this jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/beatak/7UrGA/show/

I want to make a text looking straight. By changing `overflow-x:hidden` on `.boxless-select-text`, you can see the baseline shifting.  It does NOT happen on Webkit Browsers (Google Chrome and Safari).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.boxless-select-text {
    ...
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Firefox and IE behavior is the one [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) requires:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

The reason it's not happening in WebKit is because of https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36084 (which they're not fixing because they have Apple-proprietary content of various sorts that depends on the bug, as far as I can tell).  That bug report also has the relevant spec text and reference.

Comment: so this is actually WebKit bug?  Interesting.